# How to convert String to Int with Nan data

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to convert string data to int to remove decimal point as Integer.
It has float format data in data frame.

If the column does not have nan data, it works.
However if nan data is like following code, it does not work.

```
df = pd.Dataframe([[1, '1.0'], [2, ''], [3, '2.8']],
                  columns=['id', 'number'])
df.loc[:, 'number'] = df['number'].astype(float).astype(int)
```

How can I do for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) for convert non numeric to `NaN`s.

If use pandas `0.24+` is possible use [Nullable integer data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html):

```
#get values before `.`
s = df['number'].str.split('\.').str[0]
df['number'] = pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').astype('Int64')
```

Or use `np.floor`:

```
df['number'] = pd.to_numeric(df['number'], errors='coerce').apply(np.floor).astype('Int64')
```

Or:

```
df['number'] = np.floor(pd.to_numeric(df['number'], errors='coerce'))
df['number'] = df['number'].astype('Int64')
```